# GET Custom_fields in List of Templates DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I tried to use a GET call in POSTMAN to get the List of Templates and include the Custom Field, but the response does not return the custom_fields value, any thoughts?

**GET**:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/templates?include=recipients,documents,custom_fields
```

**RESPONSE**

```
 {
        "templateId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "name": "DEMO",
        "shared": "true",
        "password": "",
        "description": "",
        "lastModified": "2017-06-20T14:13:57.9270000Z",
        "pageCount": 2,
        "uri": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "folderName": "DEMO",
        "folderId": "617c1361-8576-4b62-930e-735442256a25",
        "folderUri": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "owner": {
            "userName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "userId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "email": "XXXXXXXXX@XXXX.COM"
        },
        "documents": [
            {
                "documentId": "1",
                "uri": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "name": "DS_DEMO.pdf",
                "order": "1",
                "pages": "1",
                "display": "inline",
                "includeInDownload": "true",
                "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
                "templateLocked": "false",
                "templateRequired": "false",
                "documentGroup": "content"
            },
            {
                "documentId": "54582351",
                "uri": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png",
                "order": "2",
                "pages": "1",
                "display": "inline",
                "includeInDownload": "true",
                "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
                "templateLocked": "false",
                "templateRequired": "false",
                "documentGroup": "content"
            }
        ],
        "emailSubject": "Please sign this DS Document",
        "emailBlurb": "Thank you for reaching and showing us your interest in how DocuSign works. Please, practice here.\n\n",
        "signingLocation": "Online",
        "authoritativeCopy": "false",
        "enforceSignerVisibility": "false",
        "enableWetSign": "false",
        "allowMarkup": "true",
        "allowReassign": "true",
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [
                {
                    "defaultRecipient": "false",
                    "signInEachLocation": "false",
                    "email": "",
                    "recipientId": "4",
                    "accessCode": "",
                    "requireIdLookup": "false",
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "note": "",
                    "roleName": "System Analyst",
                    "status": "created",
                    "deliveryMethod": "email",
                    "templateLocked": "false",
                    "templateRequired": "false",
                    "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": "false",
                    "documentVisibility": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "visible": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "documentId": "54582351",
                            "visible": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "defaultRecipient": "false",
                    "signInEachLocation": "false",
                    "name": "DS Training",
                    "email": "",
                    "signingGroupId": "10749",
                    "signingGroupName": "DS Training",
                    "recipientId": "2",
                    "accessCode": "",
                    "requireIdLookup": "false",
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "note": "Please complete it as soon you can",
                    "roleName": "Sales Analyst",
                    "status": "created",
                    "deliveryMethod": "email",
                    "templateLocked": "false",
                    "templateRequired": "false",
                    "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": "false",
                    "documentVisibility": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "visible": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "documentId": "54582351",
                            "visible": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "agents": [],
            "editors": [],
            "intermediaries": [],
            "carbonCopies": [
                {
                    "email": "",
                    "recipientId": "3",
                    "accessCode": "",
                    "requireIdLookup": "false",
                    "routingOrder": "3",
                    "note": "",
                    "roleName": "Manager",
                    "status": "created",
                    "templateLocked": "false",
                    "templateRequired": "false",
                    "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": "false",
                    "documentVisibility": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "visible": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "documentId": "54582351",
                            "visible": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": [],
            "inPersonSigners": [],
            "recipientCount": "3"
        }
    },
```

**Reference:**

[Templates: list documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list/)

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It is a bug. Thank you for the report. I've verified it and filed DocuSign internal bug report API-7048.

In the meantime, the work-around is to use [Templates: get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/get/) for each of the templates returned by the [Templates: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list/) operation.

Comment: thank you so much Larry. Also, I see a similar issue when I try call the Template List, but now I am not getting the Tabs assigned to each signer. Recipient> Signer> tabs, I can not see all the tabs per template in the list, but If I try to get the values to each individual template, it brings me all the values needed. Is this other bug?

Comment: Did you include the query parameter? eg blah_blah?include=custom_fields ?  See the [docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/get/)

Comment: Yes, I add the recipients and custom fields https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx/templates?include=recipients,custom_fields, now the issue is with Recipients, I can see the recipients, but no the Tabs of each Signer

"recipients": {
                "signers": [
                    {
                        Tabs must be here
                        ]
                    }
                ],